# Ionic validation highlighting not working for ion-select

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have a form in Ionic app that consists of an ion-input and an ion-select. The validation highlighting works fine for the ion-input, but the ion-select is not getting highlighted (it has a required validator, but it isn't highlighted when not filled in):

[image]

Here is the reactive forms code:

```
this.thisForm = new FormGroup({
      biggerNumber:new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      selectValue:new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ])
    });
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="thisForm">
<ion-item>
  <ion-label class="randomClass" >Bigger number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" (ionBlur)="updateFields()" [(ngModel)]="biggerNumber" formControlName="biggerNumber" ></ion-input>
</ion-item> 
<ion-item>
  <ion-label >Select value</ion-label>
  <ion-select (ionSelect)="updateFields()"  formControlName="selectValue" >
  <ion-option value="value1" >value1</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button (click)="updateFields()" type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Here is a [***STACKBLITZ***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zebp5m?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) that shows the issue.

Comment: you mean you want it red highlighted by default or when you click on save it should be highlighted if it is not filled ?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that. When clicking on save.

Comment: Sounds similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832992/angular-6-this-formgroup-updatevalueandvalidity-not-working-properly