# How can we set errors on form array control dynamically on initally page load

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9, formarray

In one of my requirements, I have form an array-like grid table contains rows and columns. once on Init i am doing a service call and get the columns and values and error messages. based on that i have created a form array for that columns and each columns have errormessage if errormessage exists need to set errors.

I can able to set value for those columns but not able to set errors while pushing into form array i don't know how could I push error as well. stuck on this line.

Qn?
On initially how we could set the errors in form array controls based on service response error messages
i can able to see lots of demo only for set the value initially and set the validators for that controls.

But in my case i need to set error and set a value basedon server response.

**eg) response is**

```
  [
    {fieldName:'productId',fieldValue:'123',errorMessage:'Product Id should be alphanumeric'},
    {fieldName:'productname',fieldValue:'123',errorMessage:'Product name should be 10 characters'}],
```

etc

```
onInit(){
```

**// do the service call and get values once get values to push into formArray.But how could push the error as well.**

**Value is working fine**

```
let result= service response;

     result.forEach((item:any[], index) => {

 let formData =this.formBuilder.group({
            item.fieldName:[item.fieldValue],
            item.fieldName:[item.fieldValue]
        
        });
        this.formArr.push(formData);
      
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call formData.setErrors({errorMessage:item.errorMessage}) before pushing to formArr.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is the use of `updateValueAndValidity();`

```
formData.updateValueAndValidity();
```

But there are some cautions that need to be understood.

1. these work fine on a individual formControl level.
2. But on a formGroup and formArray level, it'll only update the validity of its ancestors. Those are already detailed here [Angular 6, this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity() not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832992/angular-6-this-formgroup-updatevalueandvalidity-not-working-properly) and [Angular 6, this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity() not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832992/angular-6-this-formgroup-updatevalueandvalidity-not-working-properly)
3. The workaround for that is slightly odd but you could iterate and make this happen on these lines.

   ```
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
         this.form.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
       });
   ```

Comment: How to push the error to the  form array while created field . value can be inserted like this but i don't know how to set the errors `let formData =t his.formBuilder.group({
            item.fieldName:[item.fieldValue],
            item.fieldName:[item.fieldValue]
        
        });
        this.formArr.push(formData);` after pushing to the form array again I take the form array and set the errors based on that field .